# How to import cookies with XPCOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom

How can I use XPCOM to import cookies in browser ? This is the documentation I read.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieManager

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Since the release of Firefox 57 in November 2017, XPCOM is purely an internal Firefox API -- it is not available for use by web sites or extensions.

If you are developing a Firefox extension, use [the `cookies` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Work_with_the_Cookies_API).

If you are developing a web site, you cannot interact with cookies outside your domain.

Comment: I am making a JavaScript code that needs to import cookies. JS code is executed via iMacros FireFox addon. Is it possible?